# Can't figure out how to get Higan working with OpenGL

Tags: emulation

I'm trying to get Higan working. I can't figure out how to avoid this error:

```
Error: OpenGL 3.2 is not avaliable. Select another video driver on the Advanced Configuration tab and restart again.
```

I've tried installing `libgl1-mesa-dev` and `libglu1-mesa-dev` and `mesa-util`. Nothing. Ignoring the error results in a black screen. (If it matters, I'm running a rom of Super Mario World). I have the Pi 3 model B.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi only supports OpenGL ES 2.0, and with the open source driver, OpenGL 2.0 (almost entirely).  An app that requires OpenGL 3.2 would require that you install a software renderer that can do 3.2, which I don't believe exists for ARM.

You're going to need to do what the error message says, and choose a different renderer in the app.

Comment: I picked a new emulator, fceux.